# Loop through all Nodes and update values in Java

Tags: java, xml, regex, xml-parsing

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to loop through all the nodes in an XML string then updating the values. Please be aware I'm still fairly new with Java.

My aim is to go through every Element and Attribute then run a RegEx on each value to make sure the fields contain only a predefined set of characters. If the field contains unwanted characters then these will be removed and the field updated.

I'm probably doing this completly wrong but the problem comes in when trying to edit the children of children, please see my code below.

```
protected NodeList checkXML(Node node, String strStripCharsRegEx) {
    String strNodeResult = "";
    //NodeList nodeResult = null;

    // do something with the current node instead of System.out
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

    strNodeResult = "";
    if(node.getNodeValue() != null && node.getNodeValue() != "")
    {
        for(char c : node.getNodeValue().toCharArray()) {
            if(Character.toString(c).matches(strStripCharsRegEx))
                strNodeResult = strNodeResult + c;
            }

        if(strNodeResult != "")
        {
            node.setNodeValue(strNodeResult);
        }   
    }

    if(node.hasAttributes())
    {
        NamedNodeMap XMLAttributes = node.getAttributes();
        if(XMLAttributes != null)
        {
            for(int attribIndex=0; attribIndex< XMLAttributes.getLength(); attribIndex++)
            {
                System.out.println("AttribName = " + XMLAttributes.item(attribIndex).getNodeName());
                if(XMLAttributes.item(attribIndex).getNodeValue() != null)
                {
                    if(XMLAttributes.item(attribIndex).getNodeValue() != null && XMLAttributes.item(attribIndex).getNodeValue() != "")
                    {
                        strNodeResult = "";
                        for(char c : XMLAttributes.item(attribIndex).getNodeValue().toCharArray()) 
                        {
                            if(Character.toString(c).matches(strStripCharsRegEx))
                                strNodeResult = strNodeResult + c;
                        }

                        if(strNodeResult != "")
                        {
                            XMLAttributes.item(attribIndex).setNodeValue(strNodeResult);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("AttribValue = " + XMLAttributes.item(attribIndex).getNodeValue());  
                }
            }
        }
    }           

    //Check for Children
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

    if(nodeList != null && node.hasChildNodes())
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                if(currentNode.hasChildNodes())
                {
                    //calls this method for all the children which is Element
                    checkXML(currentNode, strStripCharsRegEx);                  
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    return nodeList;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: can we see the XML file element structure.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? Does the code error or does it just not have the behaviour you were expecting?

Comment: If you are sure about the patterns,and need to replace on the whole file then why don't run run Regular expression  on the whole string to remove the patterns to verify only if the value is between key="value" for attribute and <element/> for elements, which is faster as well.

Comment: Phani - That would be a much better way, Do you have an example of a regex to do this? I was originally doing it this way but 3 of the characters we don't want to allow are "<",">" and """ so it caused a problem.

Comment: Jim - the code doesn't error but it only strips the first level of the XML, I can't get it to strip all the children.

Answer (score 1):

firstly you don't need to parse XML yourself , lots of XML parser are available for parsing XML, you can edit value after parsing and again convert them to XML.
you can use dom4j for this.

http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to be writing this kind of code in Java? It is so much easier in XSLT, which was designed for exactly this job. And you can easily invoke XSLT from Java.